# Appending to lists results from SQL

Tags: python, sql-server, list

I have a SQL Server database that has a table that lists other tables along with some meta data on them. I can pull this out through Python into a List. What I want to do then though is query each table for the number of rows in it and then append the result into my list.

So for example, I run the first part of the script and I get a List of items, each one containing a list of 3 items (name,activity, Table Name). I then want to cycle through my list, pick up the third item, use it in my SQL query and then append the result into a 4th item in the list.

It starts off

```
[[table1, act1, Table_1],[table2, act2, Table_2],[table3, act3, Table_3]]
```

The second part, first takes Table_1, counts the rows and then appends it the list

```
[[table1, act1, Table_1,10],[table2, act2, Table_2],[table3, act3, Table_3]]
```

and then for list 2 etc

```
[[table1, act1, Table_1,10],[table2, act2, Table_2,16],[table3, act3, Table_3]]
```

Tried a few things but not got any further!

Thanks in advance.

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(connetStr)
cursor = conn.cursor()

wffList=[]
cursor.execute('SELECT C_NAME,C_ACTIVE, C_TABLE_NAME from T_FORM_HEAD')
for row in cursor:
    wffList.append(row)

for row in wffList:
    tabName=row[2]
    quer=('SELECT Count(*) FROM '+ tabName)
    cursor.execute(quer)
    rowCount=cursor.fetchone()
```

Comment: where is the problem? do you get value `rowCount` ? Create new list with all four values and append to new list with rows.

Comment: Does that look ok so far?  Do i just need a few extra lines there?

Answer (score 0):

You can creat new list and append row with all four values

```
new_results = []

for row in wffList:
    tabName = row[2]

    quer = ('SELECT Count(*) FROM '+ tabName)
    cursor.execute(quer)
    rowCount = cursor.fetchone()

    row.append(rowCount)

    new_results.append(row)

print(new_results)
```

Or you can use enumerate to get row's number

```
for number, row in enumerate(wffList):
    tabName = row[2]

    quer = ('SELECT Count(*) FROM '+ tabName)
    cursor.execute(quer)
    rowCount = cursor.fetchone()

    wffList[number].append(rowCount)

print(wfflist)
```

---

But probably you could also write one SQL query to get all at once.

But it could be to complex for me at this moment.